# pear quickfrom throws code at the top of the page

Tags: php, pear

I started using PEAR yesterday, but Im having trouble.

When I launch the app, there is a bunch of QuickForm code at the tom of the page before the app.
[image]

I have followed the installation instructions from pear to the word.
Downloaded packages (including QuickForms), added the the path variables.

But for some reason it does this. I can not paste the code here as it is quite broken up into a lot of files. But maybe someone has come across something like this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set PEAR DB's debug level to non-zero value.

Set it to:

```
DB_DataObject::debugLevel(0);
```

Reference:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db-dataobject.db-dataobject.debuglevel.php

Comment: Hi Thanks. I read the manual and it makes senese, but in this cas it was a setting in `php.ini` `short_open_tag` that needed to be set to `On`. Thanks for the help anyways.